# Finding the general solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, euler-lagrange-equation

> $y''+\frac{2}{x}y' = \frac{1}{x^2}$
>
> Homo. Solution: $y= A+B\frac{1}{x}$
>
> Part. Solution: Using Lagrange's method:
>
> $y_p=A(x)+B(x)\frac{1}{x}$
>
> Assumption:
>
> $A'(x)+B'(x)\frac{1}{x} = 0 \rightarrow A'(x) = -B'(x) \frac{1}{x} (1)$
>
> $A'(x)*0 - B'(x)\frac{1}{x^2} = \frac{1}{x^2} \rightarrow B'(x) = -1\ (2)$
>
> $\Rightarrow B = -x$
>
> Add (2) to (1) $\Rightarrow A'(x) = \frac{1}{x} \Rightarrow A = ln(x)$
>
> Part. Solution: $y_p=ln(x) - 1$
>
> I believe I made a mistake somewhere. May you show me?

Comment: It is OK, I think... Check that $y_p$ you got is a solution.

Comment: Well, but then it's a different result than georg's, or my other solution below.

Comment: You found by Lagrange method $A + B/x + \ln(x) -1$ ... georg found $\ln(x) - C_1/x + C_2$ ... your problem: show they are the same solution.

Comment: I suppose, georg's $C_1 = x-B $ of me?

Comment: No, $C_1$ must be a constant, not depending on $x$.  So $C_1 = -B$ and $C_2 = A-1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT

I would say simplify

$\displaystyle y''+\frac{2}{x}y' = \frac{1}{x^2}$

$\displaystyle y'=p, y''=p'\Rightarrow p'+\frac{2}{x}p = \frac{1}{x^2}\Rightarrow p = c_1\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x}=y'\Rightarrow y =\ln x -\frac{C_1}{x}+C_2$

Comment: >Well, that's one way to solve it. The other way will be: 
>
>Assume $y_p = A * ln(x) \Rightarrow y'_p = \frac{A}{x} \Rightarrow y''_p = -\frac{A}{x^2} $
>
>Put them to the original equation, will get me the same result as your. However I'd like to know, why Lagrange'method gives me a different result. Thanks again.